# Do statements within a PL/pgSQL function run sequentially?

Tags: postgresql

I'd like to run the `create_company_maybe_race_condition()` function below, but think it might create a race condition if plpgsql functions don't run sequentially. I'm on Postgres 12.

My real world scenario is that I have Row Level Security turned on for all of my tables. The RLS check relies on an access control list in a `permissions` table. When I add a row to a table, I can't use the `RETURNING` clause since there isn't a row in the `permissions` table yet that'll allow the user to read the object.

```sql
CREATE TABLE companies (
    PRIMARY KEY(company_id),
    company_id uuid,
);

CREATE TABLE departments (
    PRIMARY KEY (department_id),
    department_id uuid DEFAULT gen_random_uuid(),
    name          text,
    company_id    uuid REFERENCES companies
);

/**********/
CREATE FUNCTION create_company_maybe_race_condition () 
RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE
    v_company_id := gen_random_uuid();
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO companies (company_id)
         VALUES (v_company_id);

    INSERT INTO departments (company_id, name)
         VALUES (v_company_id, 'My Department'); -- Postgres doesn't know that it depends on companies

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

/**********/
CREATE FUNCTION create_company_no_race_condition () 
RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE
    v_company_id uuid;
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO companies (company_id)
         VALUES (DEFAULT)
         RETURN company_id INTO v_company_id;

    INSERT INTO departments (company_id, name)
         VALUES (v_company_id, 'My Department');

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Yes, they do run sequentially. Most migration tools like knex.js rely on this sequential way of running scripts to make sure migrations are done correctly.

Comment: There is no difference between those two implementations. Your implied "race condition" isn't one. Just because you use a `RETURNING` clause doesn't mean there is a "dependency" between the two tables. Both functions will work exactly the same way. The only difference is _when_ you create the new `company_id`. If you want to establish a dependency between the two tables you need to use a foreign key.